# vertical align text in two different div's inside another div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to vertical align text inside two div's. I have tried a number of solutions found here  but none produce the required result.

I have crated a sjFiddle:

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
}

#inner1 {
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

#inner2 {
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#outer {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#inner1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#inner2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">
    Test text 1
  </div>
  <div id="inner2">
    Test text 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see how I can do this based on the code in my fiddle.
Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6t0pjgwz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this similar to what you are trying to achieve?

```css
#outer {
    height:100%;
    padding:10% 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#inner1 {
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}


#inner2 {
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }
#outer {
    background-color: purple;
}
#inner1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#inner2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner1">
         Test text 1
     </div>
     <div id="inner2">
         Test text 1
    </div>
</div>
```

I have removed the positioning from the inner divs and made them flexboxes, thus allowing us to use justify-content and align-items to achieve horizontal and vertical centering.